# GUI for Subversion on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gui, subversion, version-control

Windows has a very good lightweight tool called TortoiseSVN, which provides a simple but effective GUI for controlling SVN repositories. In Ubuntu there is a similar one called RabbitVCS.

*What GUI VCS/SVN tools are available that work effectively on a Raspberry Pi running the NOOBS Raspbian?* I am aware that there are several CLI variants, but really I want a GUI over a command line.

Comment: Note, depending on what editor you use, you might also look for a plugin to use subversion directly from that editor.

Comment: Almost every software that works on Ubuntu on a PC also works on Raspbian on a Raspberry Pi.